# Web Shoutbox Idea

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hello I was thinking about making a shoutbox for my site. I don't want to use any others because it doesn't fit in well with my pre-existing members database. I thought of some ideas but I'm not really sure on a better way of doing this. I want to submit a form and without 'GET' send a shout. I also can't re-load the page. That's where AJAX comes in :p

I thought of setting up the form on my webpage as:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return sendShout()" >
    <input type="text" name="Shout" id="Shout" />
</form>
```

With my javascript being the following:

```
<script>
    function sendShout()
    {
     if(ShoutTime == 0)
     {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open("GET", location.href+"?shout="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Shout").value)+"&name="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value), true);
      http.send();
      ShoutTime = <?php echo $shoutWait;?>+1;
      ShoutWait();
      unidle();
      document.getElementById("Shout").value='';
     }
     else
     {
      ShoutWaitNote();
      getLogs();
     }
     return false;
    }
</script>
```

then on the page I could put into the databse like $_GET['shout']... etc.

Now is there a better way to use ajax to send a shout to a mysql database without having the shout as a GET in the url?

Comment: Why don't you want to use GET?

Comment: The POST method is prefered for this.  You are not asking it for some data you would like to GET, but rather would like to POST some data to the server.

Comment: because on the homepage, if the user added '#' to the url then the shoutbox would like recurse into itself (because ?shout= wasn't there.)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand yes I would like to post, but with also not having to reload the page.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something wrong here. I suggest a PHP file dedicated to your shoutbox ajax api, rather than including shoutbox processing in your content pages. My sense is things are getting a bit muddled and leading to confusing situations.

Comment: You can do an AJAX POST.  Usually people use jQuery or a similar library for this, but Mozilla published a nice [mini-framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#A_little_vanilla_framework) that ajaxifies your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are bigger problems at hand here, but you can do a POST with XMLHttpRequest like so:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", location.href);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send("shout=something&name=something");
```

As opposed to the GET version:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", location.href + "?shout=something&name=something");
http.send();
```

You'll want to apply URL encoding in both cases. Good luck.